# Wide character Windows

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-16

Windows defines the `wchar_t` symbol to be 16 bits long. However, the `UTF-16` encoding used tells us that some symbols may actually be encoded with 4 bytes (32 bits).

Does this mean that if I'm developing an application for `Windows`, the following statement:

```
wchar_t symbol = ... // Whatever
```

might *only represent a part of the actual symbol?*

---

And what will happen if I do the same under `*nix`, where `wchar_t` is 32 bits long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it means that `symbol` may hold a part of a surrogate pair on Windows. On `*nixes` `wchar_t` is 32 bit long and will hold the whole Unicode character set. Note that a Unicode code-point doesn't represent a character, since some characters may be encoded by more than one Unicode code-point, thus it doesn't make sense to count characters at all. In particular this implies that it doesn't make sense to use anything other than UTF-8 encoded narrow-char strings anywhere outside Unicode libraries, even on Windows.

Read [this old thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful) for details.

Comment: You mistook _code point_ for _code unit_. Each character is associated with only one code point and may be represented by more than one code unit.

Comment: @ExpExc: No, I didn't. A character may be represented by more than one *codepoint*, and of course by more than one *codeunit*. E.g. `U+0061 U+U0306` is two *code-points* and represents the single character "á". In CJK scripts it's even more apparent.

Comment: Also on Windows, you should NOT use UTF-8 encoded strings when interacting with the OS, since the OS doesn't natively interpret UTF-8 strings.  When interacting with Windows APIs, you should use UTF-16 strings.  If you insist on using UTF-8, you need to call MultiByteToWideChar (specifying CP_UTF8) to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 before passing string to the Windows APIs.  It's far easier to simply code your application as  UTF-16 application than to deal with the UTF-8->UTF-16 conversion.  8 bit characters in Windows are NOT UTF-8 - they're either in the ANSI code page or in the OEM coe page.

Comment: ... and due to an old & deeply rooted Windows bug (multi-byte is interpreted as double-byte) you can't set `CP_UTF8` as the ANSI code page.